# Create a custom Gutenberg Masonry Block for Custom Post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm starting to develop with **Gutenberg** after some years developing with WordPress

I've created some simple blocks, but now I need some advice on how to create what I have in mind:

I have a portfolio custom post with some custom fields and taxonomies, for example, client, year, category, etc

I want to display the most recent portfolio items in a Gutenberg block in a masonry format, having some items bigger than others, here's where I don't know how to proceed:

1. Extend the [Query Loop Block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/extending-the-query-loop-block/) to be able to display the custom post type. My doubts are:

- How can I display the custom post meta I have?
- It is possible to change the variation layout to masonry for example?

2. Create a New Block to apply the specific design. I can't seem to find info on how to do a custom query inside a custom block

What would be the right way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend your first approach of either extending the query block or using its existing configurations to display the results you need. Study the the [attributes of the query block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/query/block.json) and how its built to better understand how you can extend it for your needs.

> How can I display the custom post meta I have?

There is [a guide in the Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/metabox/) that takes you through the most common scenarios. In similar projects, I created a new block named "post-meta" based on [Step 2 in the guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/metabox/#step-2-add-meta-block) where all the block does is display meta values for a given post type. I took this further and have each of the different post meta values registered as a [block variation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) so I can quickly choose which one to insert into a template or pattern. Eg.

```js
const variations = [
    {
        name: 'start-date',
        title: 'Start Date',
        icon: 'clock',
        attributes: {
            metaKey: 'start_date',
            ...
        }
    },
...
]
```

> It is possible to change the variation layout to masonry for example?

When you add a new Query Block, you can choose [a pattern](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-patterns/) to control the display of the results. By [registering your own block pattern](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-patterns/#register_block_pattern), you could create a masonry layout and restrict it via allowed `postTypes` to only your custom portfolio post type. At this point, CSS could be used to manipulate the content into [a masonry layout.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout)

Also, you could try extending the [save() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getsaveelement) of one/more blocks in your block pattern to include another attribute or meta value for which to base your CSS selectors that determine size/prominence. Remember, there are many ways to get to the same end goal in this case and experimenting is half the fun.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, that's a great help, I found out about meta-boxes but didn't think of patterns in a way to change the layout. I was in a hurry so I ended up developing a custom dynamic block with php render on the frontend but sure I will try this way on my next block!